# Tenses in reported idea

Tags: tense

I'm not sure about the tenses I chose for my [question](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/41277/has-the-ban-of-single-use-plastics-sparked-innovation-in-biodedgradable-recyclab) on Economics SE

> One of the [rationales](https://ec.europa.eu/environment/circular-economy/pdf/single-use_plastics_impact_assessment.pdf) of the single-use plastics ban [adopted](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=celex%3A32019L0904)
> by  the EP in 2019 **is** that it **will** spark innovation in cheap
> biodegradable recyclable plastics. Has any progress been registered in
> this regard?

The directive has already been adopted but it is yet to come in effect. Would a native speaker say: *was* and *would* in that sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends on the context.

If the rationale is still that the ban will spark innovation, **is** and **will** fit. In your example, the second sentence makes it clear that this prospect may still exist.

If the rationale of the ban is no longer expected to spark innovation, **was** and **would** are appropriate.

For example:

> One of the rationales of the single-use plastics ban adopted by the EP in 2019 was that it would spark innovation in cheap biodegradable recyclable plastics. It is now clear that this expectation has been disappointed.